# SELECT error 'No Value Given for one of more required parameters'

Tags: sql, excel, select

I'm trying to produce an Excel workbook which connects to my access database and extracts values from a table based on whether those records have a Request_Date between two strings.

The code I have written works fine if I substitute the strings for actual dates however when I then try to replicate this with strings I get the above error, followed by an additional error 'Operation is not allowed when the object is closed'

Below is the code I am using:

```
Public Sub RetrievePaymentMI()
Dim Date1 As Date
Dim Date2 As Date
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MIdb As String
Dim MIpass As String

Sheets("Data").Range("B5:N1000").Clear

Date1 = Sheets("Summary").Cells(3, 4).Value
Date2 = Sheets("Summary").Cells(4, 4).Value

OpenDataBase MIdb, MIpass

sSQL = "SELECT Policy_Number, Customer_Name, Request_Date, Payment_Type, Dual_Amt, Int_Amt, DnI_Amt, Resolve, Payment_Method, Payment_Description, Further_Info, TL_Name, Status " & _
"FROM tblData " & _
"WHERE Request_Date > Date1 AND Request_Date < Date2 "   

RetrieveDataBaseData (sSQL)

Sheets("Data").Cells(5, 2).CopyFromRecordset RecordSet

RecordSet.Close
MIDatabaseconnection.Close

MsgBox "Complete"

End Sub
```

I've attempted numerous different ways of doing this, I've  declared Date1 & Date2 as strings and dates, I've changed their names. I've attempted enclosing them in # #, " " & ' '.

HELP!!

Comment: What is the value of the two dates?

Comment: I've a userform in excel that allows the user to select from a calendar, this then puts Date1 in Sheets("Summary").Cells(3, 4).Value and Date2 Sheets("Summary").Cells(4, 4).Value.   These are formatted to ddmmyyyy same as the database.

Comment: Ok, so when the procedure is executed, what are the two values?

Comment: At this moment they are set to 10/01/2016 and 15/01/2016 on the WS.